# Display related records using different IDs

Tags: sql

I'm trying to put together a query which allows a user to input any of the id's and return any record in relation to that family.

| table.date | table.member_id | table.external_id | table.person_id | table.group_id | table.family |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | abc | 123 | 100 | xxx | Self |
| 2021-02-01 | abc | 123 | 100 | xxx | Self |
| 2021-03-01 | abc | 123 | 100 | xxx | Self |
| 2021-02-01 | abc | 234 | 101 | xxx | Spouse |
| 2021-02-01 | abc | 345 | 102 | xxx | Child1 |
| 2021-02-01 | abc | 456 | 103 | xxx | Child2 |
| 2021-01-01 | def | 321 | 200 | yyy | Self |
| 2021-01-01 | def | 432 | 201 | yyy | Spouse |
| 2021-01-01 | def | 543 | 202 | yyy | Child1 |

Output I'd like to achieve

Example 1: If I query **person_id '100'**, It would return the self, spouse, and child with the **member_id 'abc'**

| table.date | table.member_id | table.external_id | table.person_id | table.group_id | table.family |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | abc | 123 | 100 | xxx | Self |
| 2021-02-01 | abc | 123 | 100 | xxx | Self |
| 2021-03-01 | abc | 123 | 100 | xxx | Self |
| 2021-02-01 | abc | 234 | 101 | xxx | Spouse |
| 2021-02-01 | abc | 345 | 102 | xxx | Child1 |
| 2021-02-01 | abc | 456 | 103 | xxx | Child2 |

Example 2: **external_id '321'** would return all member_id and family for 'def'

| table.date | table.member_id | table.external_id | table.person_id | table.group_id | table.family |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-01-01 | def | 321 | 200 | yyy | Self |
| 2021-01-01 | def | 432 | 201 | yyy | Spouse |
| 2021-01-01 | def | 543 | 202 | yyy | Child1 |

This is what I've put together so far, but it's limited to a single ID.

```
select *
from table
    where member_id in (
        select member_id
            from table
        having count (distinct external_id) > 1
        )
    and external_id = '123'
```

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only **one** tag for the database product you are really using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It uses inner join on member_id and a sub query with the search parameters. Substitue the hard-coded '100' and '123' for a variable (i.e. `t2.person_id = @search_id`).

```
select distinct t.*
from table as t
    INNER JOIN table as t2
        ON t2.member_id = t.member_id
        and (
            t2.person_id = '100'
            OR t2.external_id = '123'
        )
```

Your query would probably work if you moved the `and external_id = '123'` inside the parentheses.

```
select *
from table
    where member_id in (
        select member_id
        from table
        where external_id = '123'
    )
```

Comment: Yep, this pretty much gets me to where I need to be, thank you. I just need to add some parameter's to allow for a user to select the 'id' of choice. I have a couple case statements for each which will likely meet that. Thanks again